# Unicode Character in Core Graphics

Tags: objective-c, unicode, pdf-generation, core-graphics

I have an iPad app where I am storing some unicode (non-ASCII) data in a SQLite DB.  Later, I retrieve that data and need to write it to a pdf. All ASCII data does fine, but the unicode data is presenting as "encoded characters"

The process goes like this:
Retrieve the data and write it to the console.  This goes fine.  Here is the output to the console:  LOOKUP:↑ to enable all activities:FOR:COORDINATIONGOAL:

(The little up arrow is my unicode character)

At this point, the data is stored in an NSString.  So next, I convert it to a char so I can use it in core graphics:

```
NSString *t = [data objectForKey:pi.persistencekey];
char *text = " ";

if ([t length] > 0) {           
  text = [t UTF8String];            
}

CGContextShowTextAtPoint (pdfContext,  pi.x, pageRect.size.height - pi.y, text, strlen(text));
```

The PDF generates fine, but the text generated shows strange characters where the up arrow is supposed to be.

I have tried other decoding methods and none work.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: have you read  Matt Gallagher post--> http://cocoawithlove.com/2011/01/advanced-drawing-using-appkit.html

Answer (score 1):

CGContextShowTextAtPoint has some known weaknesses with drawing unicode.  Basically it doesn't.

You have two options:

1. NSString's drawAtPoint and it's friends.  They can be found by searching doc for UIStringDrawing.
2. or if you need to go low-level, Core Text.

Most of the time (99%) 1. is good enough.